# Calculating the sum for a chosen date

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a range of dates & a drop down in cell B1

What you need to do is write a formula / macro / list of formulas to arrive at the total LIH target till the date chosen (B1)

Example if I chose 6th APR, it should return 798 (total of 1st to 6th April) in the yellow cell

Date    6-Apr

```
Date    Client Target   
1-Apr   189.92  
2-Apr   199.52  
3-Apr   174.58  
4-Apr   172.66  
5-Apr   61.39   
6-Apr       
7-Apr   177.13  
8-Apr   160.51  
9-Apr   179.69  
10-Apr  212.52  
11-Apr  196.97  
12-Apr  35.54
```

Comment: What we "need to do"? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this write`=SUM(B1:B6)`in the cell where you want sum.This will return you a sum from B1 to B6. you can vary B6 place from B2 to B12.